# How to fix subversion client "Can't upgrade 'some/dir' as it is not a working copy root

Tags: svn

I'm in the process of trying to update a very old server that was running subversion client version 1.6 to something newer and I'm running into a strange error message.  I've google around but haven't found anything that clarifies it.  Does anyone know what I can do to deal with a directory in my repository that is a Subversion External?

After I install a more recent version of the subversion client (on debian, FWIW) and run "svn upgrade" it fails with:

```
svn: warning: W205011: Error handling externals definition for 'conf/some_dir':
svn: warning: W155019: Can't upgrade '/home/myhome/svn/the_project/conf/some_dir' as it is not a working copy root
```

What is one supposed to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case it's helpful to anyone else.

In my case what had happened was that the conf/some_dir directory had been defined via svn:externals but someone had thereafter somehow added it as a direct local member of the repository.  In effect the svn:externals definition was overshadowed by the local child.  This meant that some operations would operate normally, things like update, commit, etc.  Other operations though would come across the svn:externals definition and become very confused.

I resolved this by trying to get the repo to a state where it only had the local child directory.  This by renaming the local directory in the repository (on the server!) and removing the svn:externals property on the working copy, updating, then re-naming the directory back to its original name:

```
cd ~/svn/the_project
svn propdel svn:externals .
svn mv svn+ssh://my-repo-server/the_project-repo/conf/some_dir svn+ssh://my-repo-server/the_project-repo/conf/some_dir-temp
svn update .
svn mv svn+ssh://my-repo-server/the_project-repo/conf/some_dir-temp svn+ssh://my-repo-server/the_project-repo/conf/some_dir
```

Painful but resolved it.  YMMV